# How to use verbatim strings in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to call an .exe from a server with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`

and I don't know *what's wrong* with the *path* I'm providing.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\srvonbase\\onbase 5.0$\\exe\\obClnt32.exe");`

This is what the exception I get:

`An exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: what is the error ? You need to mention the error you are getting.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"srvonbase\onbase 5.0$\exe\obClnt32.exe");`: either *escape* `\\` or use *verbatim* string `@"..."`

Comment: `@"\\server\share\directory`.. you are using `\\\` after every thing, thats not correct.

Comment: Are you intending to specify a UNC path, or do you want to specify a path relative to the root of the "current" drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# strings behave differently from Vb.Net strings.

VB.NET strings represent the exact characters you want to use. This means that if you write in VB.Net

```vb
Dim s as String
s = "\\myserver\newpath"
```

you are asking for a string being exactly `\\myserver\mypath`

However, if you simply turn it in C# as is, you'll have a different behavior:

```cs
string s;
s = "\\myserver\newpath";
```

refers to the string `\myserver
ewpath`

because the `\` character is used for escaping and add non printable characters or via unicode ordinal. Therefore

- `\\` is turned into `\`
- `\n` is turned in the new line character

To completely turn off this behavior in c#, you have to use *verbatim strings* which are prefixed by `@`:

```cs
string s;
s = @"\\myserver\newpath";
```

Note that to write `"` in verbatim strings, you have to double it: `""`.

Your string should either be

```cs
@"\\srvonbase\onbase 5.0$\exe\obClnt32.exe"
```

or

```cs
"\\\\srvonbase\\onbase 5.0$\\exe\\obClnt32.exe"
```

Comment: Thaanks!! "@"\\srvonbase\onbase 5.0$\exe\obClnt32.exe"" this one worked. kudos